# Error in Event Args

Tags: c#, datagridview

this is the code of the eventargs,The problem is the error is this "no overload for '_btnadd_click'matches delegate 'EventHandler'

```
private void _btnadd_Click (object sender, EventArgs e,DataGridViewCellEventArgs r)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {

                if ((Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("added");

                    int structureOptionId = int.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows[r.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    AddStructureOptionToLists(structureOptionId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that didn't involve needing to click an external link. _Be sure to explicitly mention the error you are receiving._

Comment: You already have a `row` reference there (from the loop). Use that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: Okay,thanks dude i forgot about the picture thing sorry

Answer (score 0):

O didn't understand why you need two EventArgs. I mean, you could create a class `MyEventArgs : EventArgs` with the properties you need and declare your EventHandler like that:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEventHandler;
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I need two EventArgs beacause the first one is for the button and the second one is for the parsing of the Data in the datagridview. But when I put DataGridViewCellEventArgs beside the first event args this error occurs "No overload for '_btnadd_click' matches delegate 'EventHandler' "

Comment: That's why I wondered if it is possible to put together two EventArgs in one method